# how to store image in web2py database which is sent by an android app

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I am developing a android app in which user will take a image from mobile phone and they will send to web server.I am using web2py for server side.
I want to know how to define table so that image can be stored in web2py sqllite db and how to store the image in db.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english .... 
I'm doing this at moment - Android Java to Python. 
I thought the better is convert the file in binary string and send via post parameter, in Java side. 
And about the python-server side, at least one field like bellow needs to be created:

`Field('mFilePath', 'string')`

And if you want, you can add one more to file name like bellow:

`Field('mFileName', 'string')`

The first field will be responsable to store file path. You will need to receive the post parameter and, using the python os library, convert, save the file wherever you want. You should save it at the web2py uploads folder.

Comment: Did you are in doubt yet?
I built a solution for this case, and i can share both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload and store an image in the web2py db this is how you can define the table:

```
db.define_table('image',
   Field('title', unique=True),
   Field('picture', 'upload'),
   format = '%(title)s')
```